# Готовые решения для CMS

Tags: cms

Подскажите, какие "cms" существуют для сайта, с депонированием средств? Т.е. когда две стороны хотят договориться, одна вносит деньги на счет, они хранятся на счету сайта, а второй стороне переходят когда первая подтвердит, что работа выполнена (типа бирж фриланса).

Он должен быть уже готовым, доработанным продуктом.

Answer (score 2):

Сборка фриланс-биржи на Cotonti и плагин [Сделка без риска](http://cotonti.cmsworks.ru/catalog/plugins/sbr) .

> Плагин позволяет организовать на сайте фриланс-биржи возможность
>   пользователям оформлять между собой сделки с полным согласованием всех
>   этапов работ. При этом бюджет сделки резервируется на счету сайта до
>   начала всех работ и выплачивается Исполнителю после приемки
>   результатов работ по каждому этапу сделки.